# Java XML transformer developed in JDK1.7.0 not working in Java 1.8 runtime

Tags: java, xml, xslt, version

Below code was developed in a JDK 1.7.0 environment a long time ago, but when application is run as a jar in a Java 1.8 runtime environment, there is always an exception when generating the transformer.

```
Source xsl = new StreamSource(ResultsHTMLTransformer.class.getResourceAsStream(styleSheetPath));
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
```

The exception is as below. I am confused on how this could happen. Shouldn't Java 1.8 be backward compatible with previous versions?

```
ERROR:  'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'replace' is not a valid object reference.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'reference'.'
           :Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'reference'.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'reference'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1015)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:789)
    at com.ibm.test.report.ResultsHTMLTransformer.transformXMLtoHTML(ResultsHTMLTransformer.java:38)
    at com.ibm.test.report.KitchenReport.main(KitchenReport.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)

Caused by: Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'reference'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.CastExpr.typeCheck(CastExpr.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.CastExpr.<init>(CastExpr.java:145)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Param.typeCheck(Param.java:160)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:487)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Template.typeCheck(Template.java:294)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:487)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Stylesheet.typeCheck(Stylesheet.java:653)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.createAST(Parser.java:412)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:483)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:974)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Unless you show us the XSLT, we can't help. You might have hit a bug in the weird copy of Xalan included in the JRE. You might have a bug in your stylesheet. You could try using a real version xalan.

Comment: One way it could happen is if the JDK has added new methods to the class you are invoking, causing your extension function call to bind to a different target method. (The JDK is developed to prevent that happening with Java client applications, but it can't stop it happening with applications that use reflexion to search the class for "best fit" methods).

Comment: Thanks for prompt responses. I just realized that the application was developed using IBM JDK, while the environment I deployed it has OpenJDK installed. This could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized that the application was developed using IBM JDK, while the environment I deployed it has OpenJDK installed. Once I deployed it to an environment with IBM JRE, it worked fine.

There might be some compatibility issues here, but can't be sure, as this is so basic a java function.

Below is output of `java -version` of IBM JDK.

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwa6470_27sr1-20140411_01(SR1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.7, JRE 1.7.0 Windows 7 amd64-64 Compressed References 20140410_195893 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R27_Java727_SR1_20140410_1931_B195893
JIT  - tr.r13.java_20140410_61421
GC   - R27_Java727_SR1_20140410_1931_B195893_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20140410_195893)
JCL - 20140409_01 based on Oracle 7u55-b13
```

Comment: Seeing a similar error ("Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.TypeCheckError: Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'boolean'"), in an application (openHAB) when running it on on OpenJDK v8 .. that app was tested on Oracle JDK, where this kind of error doesn't occur. Just writing this to confirm for others that clearly this is related to some mismatch somewhere with OpenJDK ..